# Probability and Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Could someone please provide a worked solution to this question?

A box contains 5 amber, 7 blue and 9 green balls. Six of the balls are removed from the box at random and without replacement.

Find the probability that

(a) three out of the six balls are blue;

(b) four of the balls are blue and two are green;

(c) the second ball to be selected is amber, given that the final ball to be selected is blue.

I was wondering if there is a combinatorial argument for these types of problems,  because multiplying fractions here seems a little time consuming and messy.

My answers:

(a) $\frac{7}{21}\times\frac{6}{20}\times\frac{5}{19}\times\frac{14}{18}\times\frac{13}{17}\times\frac{12}{16}\times\frac{6!}{(3!)^2}$

(b) $\frac{7}{21}\times\frac{6}{20}\times\frac{5}{19}\times\frac{4}{18}\times\frac{9}{17}\times\frac{8}{16}\times\frac{6!}{(4!)(2!)}$

Any help very much appreciated, as always.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how I can improve the question, I'm confused as to why it's received a negative rating.

Answer (score 4):

(A) The probability that when selecting $6$ from $21$ balls, you select $3$ from $7$ blue and $3$ from $14$ non-blue is: $$\dfrac{\binom 73\binom {14}3}{\binom {21}6} \tag{$= \dfrac{\frac{7\cdot 6\cdot 5}{3\cdot 2\cdot 1}\cdot \frac{14\cdot 13\cdot 12}{3\cdot 2\cdot 1}}{\frac{21\cdot 20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16}{6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}}$}$$

Which matches your answer, in more compact form.

The count of Blue balls so selected follows a [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

(B) The probability that when selecting $6$ from $21$ balls, you select $4$ from $7$ blue, $2$ from $9$ green (, and $0$ from $5$ amber) is: $$\dfrac{\binom 74\binom {9}2\color{silver}{\binom 5 0}}{\binom {21}6}$$

Which again matches your answer.

(C) The probability that when given that $1$ of the blue balls will be reserved for the sixth draw, the second ball selected will be one from the $5$ of the $20$ unreserved balls that are amber, is just:

> $$\mathsf P(C_2=a\mid C_{6}=b) = \frac{5}{20}$$

No need to overcomplicate it.

Comment: Very nice reasoning, with a concise layout.

Comment: I came across a similar problem to part (c) lately in a different context. Translated into the context of selecting colored balls from a box, it would read something like: (d) What is the probability of selecting two amber balls, given that the first ball selected is blue? Is this tackled in a similar way, or would you suggest a different method? How can I avoid overcounting in this question?

Comment: @wrb98 It is similar: The conditioned probability is that when selecting 5 from 20 remaining balls, you select 2 from 5 amber and 3 from 15 remaining non-amber.

Comment: So just multiplying the combinations would work? So it would be $\frac{5 choose 2*15 choose 3}{20 choose 5}$

Comment: @wrb98 Yes.  $\newcommand{\ch}[2]{{^{#1}\mathrm C_{#2}}} \dfrac{\ch 5 2 \ch{15}3}{\ch{20}5}$

Answer (score 1):

Well, for such combinatorical questions there are typically multiple different "counting schemes" to get to the same answer. Here is the thought process I would have to arrive at those. Hope it helps:

a) There are $\binom{5+7+9}{6}$ ways to choose the $6$ balls. There are $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ blue balls and $\binom{5+9}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ non-blue balls. So the Answer is
$\begin{align}\frac{\binom{5+9}{3}\binom{7}{3}}{\binom{5+7+9}{6}}\end{align}$

b) very similar: $\binom{7}{4}$ ways to choose $4$ blue balls. $\binom{9}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ green balls. So the answer is
$\begin{align}\frac{\binom{7}{4}\binom{9}{2}}{\binom{5+7+9}{6}}\end{align}$

Generally: It is always about the "binomial coefficient" $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ which is the number of ways to select $k$ objects (without replacement) out of a total of $n$ objects.

c) Here, order is important, so you can't use binomial coefficients in the same way. The best way here is to multiply fractions for each step like this:

$P(\text{last is blue}) = \frac{7}{5+7+9}$.

$P(\text{second is amber and last is blue}) = \frac{5}{5+7+9} \cdot\frac{7}{4+7+9}$

$P(\text{second is amber}|\text{last is blue}) = \frac{P(\text{second is amber and last is blue})}{P(\text{last is blue})} = \frac{5\cdot7\cdot21}{7\cdot21\cdot20}$

Comment: Thanks, what are your thoughts on (c)?

Comment: You have to modify the number of total events (i.e. the number below the fraction). The basic prinicple is P(2. is amber GIVEN THAT last ist blue) = P(2. is amber AND last is blue) / P(last is blue).

Comment: Yes I thought that, but it was working out the actual probabilities in the fraction that was giving me trouble. Could you give a worked explanation for that too? The ones for (a) and (b) were very helpful.

Comment: I added a solution. Though it doesn't have much in common with a/b. I started to do something with binomial coefficients again, but for the case with order, that quickly gets out of hands and becomes more messy than multiplying fractions.

Comment: @Simon In $(a),(b)$ you should not count "ways to distribute the balls" in the numerator; as the denominator is order-independent count so too must be the numerator.

Comment: @Graham-Kemp well, without the distribution-factor, the numerator would count "number of ways to choose the first three balls blue, and the latter three balls non-blue". That is not what is asked. Only by adding this factor, the numerator becomes order-independant.

Comment: @Simon  Not at all.  The probability that when selecting $6$ from $21$ balls, you select $3$ from $7$ blue and $3$ from $14$ non-blue is: $$\dfrac{\binom 73\binom {14}3}{\binom {21}6}$$
The count of Blue balls so selected follows a [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: @GrahamKemp * blush * yeah, you are absolutely correct. I edited the answer.